# Ruby on Rails Console Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am try on to insert a value via the Rails console into the database, but it's not working.

the first command  is
u=users.create(:name=>"bob",:address=>"Dublin")

this is the output after I running the first command

```
 u=Users.create(:name=>"Ben",:address=>"Dublin")
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`address`, `created_at`, `email`, `name`, `password`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Dublin', '2012-04-16 23:15:48', NULL, 'Ben', NULL, '2012-04-16 23:15:48')
   (9.1ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Users id: 2, name: "Ben", password: nil, email: nil, address: "Dublin", created_at: "2012-04-16 23:15:48", updated_at: "2012-04-16 23:15:48">
```

this is the second command
    t=tweets.create(:status=>"I am a tweet from bob",:user=>u)

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `tweets' for main:Object
    from (irb):4
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: tweets should be Tweet. Capital because its a class name, in ruby class names starts with Capital letter. If its relation then User.find(id).tweets.create(:status => "bla bla") but in this case you don't need :user => because he will know to who attach it. By Magic

Comment: Hello,thanks for help,but I am to create a valeu in tweets table which   reference in users table?

Comment: which is user_id,so I mean each tweet has a user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `Tweet` model, you want

```
u = User.first
t = Tweet.create(:status => "I am a tweet from bob", :user => u)
```

Comment: What? Are you saying that the above doesn't work either? What's the error?